# How to insert an object into array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

```
actions = [{ 'name' : 'Share',
  'icon' : 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
    },{
    'name' : 'Edit',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Embed',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
     'name' : 'Schedule',
     'icon' : 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];
```

I have to remove the second object and insert it again at same position after passing a condition . Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to remove it and not only update it?

Comment: Yes there is way to do , but what you tried so far ?

Comment: If you really want to remove it and later insert an object at the same position you should look at [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

Comment: sorry for that explanation didnt get added

Comment: i tried using splice but it is giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), that can remove any number of elements in the array, and insert any number of elements at a specified index.

```js
const actions = [
  { 'name' : 'Share', 'icon' : 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'},
  {
    'name' : 'Edit',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Embed',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
     'name' : 'Schedule',
     'icon' : 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];


const saved = actions.splice(1,1); // At position 1 (remember it is zero based), remove 1 element
console.log("Test1", actions);
console.log("Removed", saved);
actions.splice(1,0,...saved); // At position 1, remove 0, insert all saved elements
console.log("Test2", actions);
```

I assume that you are using this for some menu, and another approach would be to save the original array and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) it for the new condition, and then throw away the filtered array when it is no longer needed.

```js
const actions = [
  { 'name' : 'Share', 'icon' : 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'},
  {
    'name' : 'Edit',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Embed',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
     'name' : 'Schedule',
     'icon' : 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];


const filtered = actions.filter( item => item.name != "Edit");
console.log("Filtered", filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update the **index** `(index start from 0)` with new object

```js
const actions = [{ 'name' : 'Share', 'icon' : 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right' },{ 'name' : 'Edit', 'icon' : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right' }, { 'name' : 'Embed', 'icon' : 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right' }, { 'name' : 'Schedule', 'icon' : 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right' } ];


function replace(index,object){
  const array = actions;
  array[index] = object;
  return array
}

console.log(replace(2,{new:'one'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use splice(). To remove element at position 1:

```
actions.splice(1,1);
```

To add the item at position 1:

```
actions.splice(1,0,itemToAdd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an object to an array using `push`.

example:

```js
const actions = [{
    'name': 'Share',
    'icon': 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }, {
    'name': 'Edit',
    'icon': 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Embed',
    'icon': 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Schedule',
    'icon': 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];

var newObj = {
  name: 'thing',
  icon: 'smiley face'
}

actions.push(newObj)

console.log(actions)
```

if you want to remove the second object, then add it at the end, you could do so using filter or splice:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

```js
const actions = [{
    'name': 'Share',
    'icon': 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }, {
    'name': 'Edit',
    'icon': 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Embed',
    'icon': 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Schedule',
    'icon': 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];

var secondObj = actions[1]
actions.push(secondObj) // adds secondObj to end of array
actions.splice(1, 1) // removes one elment from index 1

console.log(actions)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove object at certain `index` keep this `index` and add at this `index` later on here is how. Here is more about [splice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

```js
var action = [{ 'name' : 'Share',
  'icon' : 'fa fa-share-alt library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
    },{
    'name' : 'Edit',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-pencil-square-o library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
    'name' : 'Embed',
    'icon' : 'fa fa-link library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  },
  {
     'name' : 'Schedule',
     'icon' : 'fa fa-calendar library_icon mylibrary-icon-right'
  }
];
var idx = -1;
var item = {"foo":"bar"};
// first step to remove element matching by condition
action.forEach(function (el,index){
  if("Edit" == el.name ){
    action.splice(index,1);
    idx=index;
    item = el;
    return ;
   }
})
console.log(`items before addition `,action);
// step 2 is inserting element at deleted index
action.splice(idx, 0, item)

console.log(`items after addition `,action);
```